# switch on / off titles to appear on mouseover

Tags: javascript, title

```
<div title='lorem ipsum'>blue sky</div>
```

By default titles are showing when pointer is hover.

Is it posible to switch this, something like:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    if (something) {turn off titles;}
    else {turn on titles;}
})
```

So they will appear on mouseover **only** if they are turned on.

Comment: yes, it is. What exactly are you going to use as event to turn it on or off depends on you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide `title` you'd remove the attribute. So something like this would work:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.aButton').click(function(){
       var existingTitle = $('.titleDiv').attr('title');
       if(existingTitle){
           $('.titleDiv').removeAttr('title');
       }
       else{
           $('.titleDiv').attr('title', $('.titleDiv').data('title'));
       }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="titleDiv" data-title='lorem ipsum'>blue sky</div>
<button class="aButton">click me</button>
```

I'm storing the attribute text in a data attribute and then setting the actual attribute depending on if it exists already or not.

Alter logic depending on need.

Comment: thanks, but I need that for entire page, for all elements.

Comment: Ok, well change the selector? This is intended as an **example** to address your problem, you need to fit this to suit your needs.

Comment: @Liam I was also thinking of something similar.